# Why are my carrots and potatoes popping out of the ground

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating a carrot and potato farm in the Nether but it is not working. Every time I plant one of them they pop out of the ground.

The light levels are ok, if I plant wheat on that land it works just fine.

Do potatoes and carrots need water to grow??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that carrots and potatoes do need water to grow. However, the Minecraft Wiki is very unclear about this and there is no way to know for sure. The best thing to do would be to go to the Overworld, plow a dirt block, and try to plant it with and without water. If it does need water, it would not be possible to grow these crops in the Nether.

Comment: Yeah I tried this, and it does not grow in the overworld either. But I think it is a bug. I think the following is happening. The farmland does not know something is planted on it, and it is not hydrated, so it turns back into dirt, and poping out what's planted on it.

Comment: Have you tried waiting until the farmland is hydrated (turns dark brown) before planting? That might be necessary.

Comment: No i haven't, but that would only work in the overworld. This will not help me at all in the Nether.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have water close enough to the spot where I want to plant the carrot, there is enough light and I prepared the land to be farmland using a hoe. But after a few seconds the carrots Pop out while the wheat just grows properly :(

Comment: Are you doing this in the overworld or in the Nether?

Comment: @SaifBechan I know. But if you treid that, then you'd have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Potatoes and carrots do need water to grow. This is because you right click on a dirt block. To let it stay in that state it needs water. Its like irrigation.

Comment: This has already been added as an answer.